# Error in my function code (stop working)

Tags: c++

I have runtime error and I don't know what's the reason .

```
void replace(char *str, char ch){
    int i=0;
    while(*(str+i) != '\0'){
        if(*(str+i) == ' '){
            *(str+i) = ch;  // I doubt in this line
        }
        i++;
    }   
    cout << str << "\t";
}

int main(){

    replace("Hello World",'_');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it in a debugger to know which line is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify "Hello World" which is a constant, read-only string.

It will work better like this:

```
char s[] = "Hello World!";
replace(s, "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

`"Hello world"` is a string literal, i.e. a `const char *`. You're not allowed to modify that. How does that even compile? It should tell you that you're not allowed to pass a `const char *` into a function that takes a `char *`.

EDIT: Of course I should provide a solution too. kotlinski already pointed it out: Writing `char myString[] = "Hello World!"` will create a char array that is a copy of the string literal. You're free to modify that (provided that you don't write out of bounds, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This Would work :- As mentioned above str is constant and hence cant be modified  as such:-

```
void replace(char *str, char ch){
int i=0;
char * strnew= new char[strlen(str) +1];
strcpy(strnew,str);
while(*(strnew+i) != '\0'){
    if(*(strnew+i) == ' '){
        *(strnew+i) = ch;  // I doubt in this line
    }
    i++;
}   
cout << strnew << "\t";
delete[] strnew;
}

int main()
{
replace("Hello World",'_');
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does `strnew` get `delete`d?

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks for correcting me ... modified the code ... Regards